# Flickering and mess up flowLayoutPanel items while scrolling in winform C#

Tags: c#, winforms, flicker, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a flowLayoutPanel that has some items .. these items are Custom UserControl I created.
When I scorll , these items get flicker.

So I Created Custom FLP and put this code in its constructor:

```
this.SetStyle(
        ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
        ControlStyles.UserPaint |
        ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
```

But it still flickers .. then I after some search found this code and added it:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

flickering Problem got solved .. but this code causes some performance issues in scrolling panel .. it gets slow and has bad UX :(

anyone can help with this problem??

Comment: Shouldn't the UserControl have the DoubleBuffer?

Comment: it has .. but didn't do anything :)

Comment: What's flickering?  The UserControl?  Document this better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this style :

```
this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
```

If this is not enough, you can manually stop and resume your form or control drawing with these methods :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessageA", ExactSpelling = true, CharSet = 
CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hwnd, int wMsg, int wParam, int lParam);

private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 0xB;

public static void SuspendDrawing(Control target)
{
    if (target != null && !target.IsDisposed)
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 0, 0);
}

public static void ResumeDrawing(Control target, bool redraw)
{
    if (target != null && !target.IsDisposed)
    {
        SendMessage(target.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, 1, 0);

        if (redraw)
            target.Refresh();
    }
}
```